# Web API to SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, webapi

In our project we have a mobile app which is connected to a Web API, now our requirement is that the Web API should call SharePoint to update a managed meta data column of an document library item. I initially thought of doing this via SharePoint REST endpoints but it seems it is not possible or difficult, I am thinking of using CSOM to update the managed metadata column for the library item. I am using SharePoint Online.

**So the following are my questions**

1. How to get the SharePoint context in Web API and then do the managed meta column update, I saw few links like [link1](https://jeremythake.com/using-the-sharepoint-csom-and-rest-api-with-office-365-api-via-azure-ad-fe59a6d1a26) [link2](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kaevans/2014/04/15/calling-o365-apis-from-your-web-api-on-behalf-of-a-user/) Is this the right approach for authenticating and getting the SharePoint context in Web API
2. Even if I get the context, is managed meta column data update doable?
3. Is there any other way we can achieve my purpose.

Thanks for reading such a long question. Your thoughts are appreciated.

Comment: Do you need to use the security context of the current user, or would a service account work? Also, what's your platform?

Comment: Thanks  for the comment. I would need the security context of the current user so that in the 'modified by' column i would get the same user. Platform means it is an iPhone app contacting the Web API which in turn needs to do the update in SharePoint online site.